# Making Oauth2 request to twitter api

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0, axios

**Updated Question:** I want to authenticate user in NodeJs using oauth2 request but I am unable to find any article to do it on web.

Twitter generally, and mostly people on web use oauth 1 for Authentication by I don't want to have express session middleware and also, I am curious to understand how can we authenticate user using oauth when they don't have passport strategy and so on.

Can someone please help me in figuring out how we can authenticate user in twitter using their docs (with code and possibly axios)?

[link for their docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token.html)

Comment: Could you post a link to where the oauth library is coming from. Make sure it is generating OAuth 1.0a authorization headers. Can you print the request logs?

Comment: It is not possible to authenticate a user on Twitter via OAuth 2. Only OAuth 1.0A is supported for user auth. Twitter only uses OAuth 2 for application-only authentication, which has no user context. So, unfortunately you will not be able to use OAuth 2 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to authenticate a *user* with OAuth2. On the documentation page you've linked to (which details `POST oauth2/token`)

> Allows a registered **application** to obtain an OAuth 2 Bearer Token, which can be used to make API requests on an application's own behalf, **without a user context**. This is called Application-only authentication.

<sup><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sup>